# Trouble controlling the Toolbar visibility

Tags: android, toolbar

I am having trouble showing and remove the Toolbar via lines of code.
It can do this?
If I'm in a fragment and want the Toolbar short and after ws loading appear.
I tried the following means no avail.

Toolbar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if(actionBar != null) {
     actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="fragContainer" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_menu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFooter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:maxWidth="690dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rodape_menu"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

CustomActionBar.xml

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

attempt code

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();

findViewById(R.id.toolbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.toolbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Could you tell me WHY have you use `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` ??? Delete that! You've already set Toolbar as your actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

What if you set the toolbar as actionbar?

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().hide();

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then you can get the actionbar and hide it or wherever you want with it.

**EDIT:** If you don't have the view in your layout, is not going to work:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

This one goes at the bottom of your RelativeLayout root layout view.

Comment: Yes I did it, because when you command does not work getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: just try it and works perfect. You may have an issue in your code. Do you really have the Toolbar in your activity xml?

Comment: No have errors in the xml. I changed my question to try to find out what might be going on.

Comment: Yes you do... you are creating inconsistencies in your code.

Comment: You mentioned that you have inconsistencies in my code? Which are they? I changed the xml (which differs would be the style) as your code and even then the getSupportActionBar().hide() does not work.

Comment: You're not reading my answers in your main question: ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); delete that. Be sure about your Style (needs to be AppCompat) and be sure you're using AppCompatActivity

Comment: I did what you said, I checked what you asked for and check the Toolbar does not disappear.

Comment: All this is wrong : 
`ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if(actionBar != null) {
     actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}` you can't do that if you already set toolbar as your actionbar, it may crash or get null values.